# Aggregation of the data using SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

The left side is the table and right side is the expected result.

1. Each "rate change" value in the action column must have a row in the output
2. If the "rate change" has its associated "completed" value then req_start date and end date will be filled.

```
create table testing(
    cw_num varchar(255),
    action varchar(255),
    action_date  datetime,
    status varchar(255)
); 

insert into testing(cw_num,action,action_date,status) values 
('g-1234','complete','2019-09-30','mission completed'),
('g-1234','action going','2019-09-29','started'),
('g-1234','action going','2019-09-28','started'),
('g-1234','rate change','2019-09-27','started'),
('g-1234','complete','2019-08-30','mission completed'),
('g-1234','action going','2019-08-29','started'),
('g-1234','action going','2019-08-28','started'),
('g-1234','rate change','2019-08-27','started'),
('g-5678','complete','2019-07-30','mission completed'),
('g-5678','action going','2019-07-29','started'),
('g-5678','action going','2019-07-28','started'),
('g-5678','rate change','2019-07-27','started'),
('g-5678','complete','2019-06-30','mission completed'),
('g-5678','action going','2019-06-29','started'),
('g-5678','action going','2019-06-28','started'),
('g-5678','rate change','2019-06-27','started'),
('g-91011','action going','2019-05-02','started'),
('g-91011','rate change','2019-05-01','started'),
('g-91011','complete','2019-04-03','mission completed'),
('g-91011','action going','2019-04-02','started'),
('g-91011','rate change','2019-04-01','started')
```

Comment: How are you determining that a particular complete is only related to a particular rate change row.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative sum to count the number of "rate change" records to define the groups that you want.

After that, the rest is just aggregation:

```
select cw_num,
       row_number() over (partition by cw_num order by min(action_date)) as seqnum,
       min(action_date) as req_start,
       max(case when action = 'complete' then action_date end) as req_end,
       max(action_date) as curr_date
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when action = 'rate change' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cw_num order by action_date asc) as grp
      from testing t
     ) t
group by cw_num, grp
order by cw_num, min(action_date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=34203224207de51470cfb901cdcedfd9) is a db<>fiddle.